# Запуск python скрипта с помощью cron в ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

Всем Привет
не могу настроить крон на запуск скрипта (телеграм бота) python3
скрипт находится здесь: /home/orbit/mng/bot.py

файл исполняемый

код выглядит вот так

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import telepot

bot = telepot.Bot('249146209:AAHiASx3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxQ')
bot.sendMessage(xxxxxxx, 'Я перезагрузился!')
```

из строки все запускается

пишу в crontab:

```
*  *    * * *   root    /home/orbit/mng/bot.py
```

тишина

Подскажите как сделать правильно?

Comment: Смотри в логах cron, добавь в скрипт отладочные сообщения вроде print('Запустился') или подобное.

Возможно что у тебя библиотека telepot установлена в .venv, а когда скрипт запускается из cron, то эта библиотека не видна скрипту

Comment: Посмотрите в /var/mail/root - если есть ошибка при выполнении, то в ящике будет письмо от крона с указанием на ошибку.

Comment: наставил принтов в код в логах /var/log/syslog написано: CRON[1500]: (root) CMD (   /home/orbit/mng/bot.py  )
Feb 19 14:43:02 1 CRON[1499]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Comment: в /var/mail пусто.  А как узнать где Telepot стоит?

Comment: @Александр `No MTA installed, discarding output` - о чем говорит?

Comment: не установлен говорит

Comment: @Александр Бинго! Поставьте exim (или postfix). `apt-get install exim4`

Comment: В логах пишет No module named 'telepot'. Как сделать так чтоб эта библиотека была видна скрипту?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно проблема связана с отсутствием pyTelegramBotAPI

```
pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI
```

https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/

Comment: автор использует tele**p**ot

Answer (score 0):

Лучше сделать venv

```
python3 -m venv /home/orbit/mng/venv
/home/orbit/mng/venv/bin/pip install telepot
```

В крон добавлять

```
/home/orbit/mng/venv/bin/python /home/orbit/mng/bot.py
```